# How to TDD in Ruby using Eclipse on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, eclipse, tdd

How to TDD the following snippet in Ruby using Eclipse on Windows?

```
class PassIntegers
  def addition(i,j)
    k = i+j
  end
end
```

Comment: Windows and Eclipse have nothing to do with it. I'd start like writing something more easily testable, right now you have to either sub print, or change stdout.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have modified the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install test-unit by executing `gem install test-unit`

Run the following snippet as `2 Ruby Test`

```
require 'test/unit'

require 'PassIntegers'
class TestPassIntegers < Test::Unit::TestCase
    def test_pass_integers
      passIntegers = PassIntegers.new
      expected = passIntegers.addition 3,2
      assert_equal expected, 5
    end
end
```

[image: ruby-test-eclipse]

**Possible issue**

If the following error occurs at the Eclipse Console:

```
C:/dev/tools/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/965/1/.cp/testing/dltk-testunit-runner.rb:252:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Test::Unit::UI::SILENT (NameError)
```

Open `C:\dev\tools\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\965\1\.cp\testing\dltk-testunit-runner.rb` and solve this by commenting

```
#autoRunner.output_level = Test::Unit::UI::SILENT
```

and adding

```
autoRunner.runner_options[:output_level] = Test::Unit::UI::Console::OutputLevel::SILENT
```

and run the test again.

Solution to solve the `uninitialized constant Test::Unit::UI::SILENT (NameError)` issue found at http://blog.christopherkaiser.de/?p=319

Comment: In eclipse MARS, to fix same error I comment the line 252 ( `autoRunner.output_level = Test::Unit::UI::SILENT` )